# Why no lever tools were used during manual valve opening attempts in Fukushima Daiichi?

Tags: valves

I watched a PBS documentary https://youtu.be/qRKScRgsUaE and Netflix series about this accident. Both show very slow and strenuous attempts to open a valve manually. Why there was no use of level tools to exert greater torque on the valve wheel? According to "Inside Japan's Nuclear Meltdown" Frontline documentary, multiple trips had to be made to open one valve due to radiation imposed time limits. Using a purpose designed or an improvised tool, e.g. a crowbar or a piece of pipe, would open a stuck valve much faster. I was surprised that a facility with kilometers of piping and hundreds of valves didn't have procedures and tools beyond a pair of human hands.

Comment: Because badly applied levers can break valves... seen it done.

Comment: @SolarMike Good point, but why not equip a nuclear power plant, which costs over \$10G to build, with a few $100 worth, lightweight, purpose built tools to quickly open stuck valves in emergency?

Comment: @PaulJurczak: What some people regard as a reasonable purchase, some companies consider an unnecessary capital cost. "Do more with less".

Comment: If a valve is designed so that people at the high end of some normal strength range won't break the valve, then giving someone in a heightened state of emergency a lever may lead to the "badly applied levers" that @SolarMike is referring to.  If I were a regulator touring your nuclear plant and you showed me your tool closet with the "emergency levers", my _immediate_ reaction would be to demand either the removal of the levers, or proof that the valves upon which they will work have been designed to withstand being opened and closed while some strong and upset person is wielding the lever.

Comment: On a nuclear submarine, a cheater on a nuclear valve would be a trip to make little rocks out of big rocks; however, in extremis those rules go out the window.

Comment: @TimWescott *giving someone in a heightened state of emergency a lever may lead to the "badly applied levers"*, but if that someone is wearing a full hazmat suit and had to make a long run to get to the valve, having a tool can make a difference between success and a failure. The tool could be placed behind "emergency use only" glass to satisfy the regulator.